# Which method dm or dbow works well for document similarity using Doc2Vec?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, similarity, doc2vec

I'm trying to find out the *similarity between 2 documents*. I'm using **Doc2vec Gensim** to train around **10k documents**. There are around **10 string type of tags**. Each tag consists of a unique word and contains some sort of documents. Model is trained using **distributed memory method**.

```
Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.0001, min_count=2, window=10, dm=1, dm_mean=1, epochs=50, seed=25, vector_size=100, workers=1)
```

I've tried both **dm** and **dbow** as well. **dm** gives better *result(similarity score)* as compared to **dbow**. I understood the concepts of **dm vs dbow**. But don't know which method is good for similarity measures between two documents.

First question: **Which method is the best to perform well on similarities?**

`model.wv.n_similarity(<words_1>, <words_2>)` gives similarity score using **word vectors**.

`model.docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs(model, doc1, doc2)` gives similarity score using **doc vectors** where doc1 and doc2 are not tags/ or indexes of doctags. *Each doc1 and doc2 contains 10-20 words kind of sentences.*

Both **wv.n_similarity** and **docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs** provide different similarity scores on same types of documents.

**docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs** gives little bit good results as compared to **wv.n_similarity** but **wv.n_similarity** sometimes also gives good results.

Question: **What is the difference between docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs and wv.n_similarity? Can I use docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs to find the similarity score between unseen data (It might be a silly question)?**

Why I asked because **docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs** provides similarity score on tags, not on actual words belonging to their tags. I'm not sure, please correct me here, if I'm wrong.

**How can I convert cosine similarity score to probability?**

Thanks.

```py
model = Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.0001, min_count=2, window=10, dm=1, dm_mean=1, epochs=50, seed=25, vector_size=100, workers=4)
# Training of the model
tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=_d, tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(<list_of_list_of_tokens>)]
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
model.train(tagged_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

# Finding similarity score
model.wv.n_similarity(<doc_words1>, <doc_words2>)
model.random.seed(25)
model.docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs(model, <doc_words1>, <doc_words2>)
```

Answer (score 6):

Both PV-DM mode (`dm=1`, the default) and PV-DBOW mode (`dm=0`) can work well. Which is better will depend on your data and goals. Once you have a robust way to quantitatively score the quality of a model's results, for your project goals – which you'll want to be able to tune all of the model's meta-parameters, including DM/DBOW mode – you can and should try both.

PV-DBOW trains fast, and often works very well on shortish-docs (a few dozens of words). Note, though, that this mode *doesn't* train usable word-vectors **unless** you also add the `dbow_words=1` option, which will slow training.

Using `model.wv.n_similarity()` relies on word-vectors only. It averages each set f word-vectors, then reports the cosine-similarity between those two averages. (So, it will only be sensible in PV-DM mode, or PV-DBOW with `dbow_words=1` activated.

Using `model. docvecs.similarity_unseen_docs()` uses `infer_vector()` to treat each of the supplied docs as new texts, for which a true `Doc2Vec` doc-vector (**not** a mere average-of-word-vectors) is calculated. (This method operates on lists-of-words, *not* lists-of-tags.)

Which is better is something you should test for your goals. The average-of-word-vectors is a simpler, faster technique for making a text-vector – but still works ok for a lot of purposes. The inferred doc-vectors take longer to calculate, but with a good model, may be better for some tasks.

Other notes on your setup:

- often, setting `min_count` as low as 2 is a bad idea: those rare words don't have enough examples to mean much, and actually interfere with the quality of surrounding words
- 10k documents is on the smallish side for a training corpus, compared to published `Doc2Vec` results (which usually use tens-of-thousands to millions of documents).
- published results often use 10-20 training epochs (though more, like your choice of 50, might be helpful especially for smaller corpuses)
- on typical multi-core machines `workers=1` will be much slower than the default (`workers=3`); on a machine with 8 or more cores, up to `workers=8` is often a good idea. (Though, unless using the newer `corpus_file` input option, more `workers` up to the full count of 16, 32, etc cores doesn't help.)
- classic `Doc2Vec` usage doesn't assign docs just known labels (as in your "10 string type of tags"), but unique IDs for each document. In some cases using, or adding, known labels as tags may help, but beware that if you're **only** supplying 10 tags, you've essentially turned your 10,000 documents into 10 documents (from the perspective of the model's view, which sees all texts with the same tag as if they were segments of one larger document with that tag). In plain PV-DBOW, training only 10 doc-vectors, of 100-dimensions each, from just 10 distinct examples wouldn't make much sense: it'd be prone to severe overfitting. (In PV-DM or PV-DBOW with `dbow_words`, the fact that the model is training both 10 doc-vectors and many hundreds/thousands of other vocabulary-word word-vectors would help offset the risk of overfitting.)

Comment: I've also tried giving `workers=3` but it results in bad similarity score. Does workers value impact on the model?

Comment: The count of `workers` should have essentially no impact on model quality. If it seems to, there may be other problems with your comparison/training, in those runs, that have ben misattributed to varying `workers`.

Comment: I've added the code to train of the model and to find the similarity score. I tried with `python2` and `python3` both. Similarity score gets changed when I change the value of the `workers` for both the versions of the python.

Comment: I feel, each time training the model(without changing parameters), gives different results. Even, passing `seed` parameter. Why is it so?

Comment: These algorithms use random-sampling at a number of steps – initialization, subsampling of training-words, sampling of negative-examples. And, using multiple threads will slightly jumble the training order on each run. So slight differences from run-to-run are to be expected. But the overall quality of results for downstream purposes should be generally the same each run – with just a little jitter in similarities/rankings/etc. If you're not seeing that, you should show an example of where two runs give very different results.

Comment: (A longer explanation of the sources of differences from run-to-run is in the Gensim FAQ: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism)